# How can I use a local file during Require.js optimisation, but a CDN-hosted version at runtime?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js, ractivejs

My page includes several components that exist as separate AMD modules. Each of these components is turned into a single file by the Require.js optimiser. Because several of these components share dependencies (e.g. jQuery and d3), the optimiser `paths` config uses CDN URLs for those dependencies, rather than bundling them into the optimised file.

Here's where it gets tricky. I've written a [module loader plugin](https://github.com/RactiveJS/requirejs-ractive) for [Ractive.js](http://ractivejs.org) called rvc.js, which allows me to include Ractive components that are defined in HTML files. (Yes, I'm asking for help on how to use my own library.)

This works fine - code like this gets optimised as you'd expect:

```
define( function ( require ) {
  var ChartView = require( 'rvc!views/Chart' );
  var view = new ChartView({ el: 'chart' });
});
```

Because Ractive is used by several of the components, it should be served from a CDN like jQuery and d3. But it's used by rvc.js during the optimisation process, which means that the `Ractive` entry for the optimiser's `paths` config can't point to a CDN - it has to point to a local file.

Is there a way to tell Require.js 'use the local file during optimisation, but load from CDN at runtime'?

Comment: set a var like  fileToUse= amILocal() ? "lib.js" : "lib.min.js"; and pass fileToUse to require instead of a hard-coded literal.

Comment: The trouble is that whichever value of `fileToUse` is given to the optimiser, that's both a) the file used during optimisation and b) the file that the optimiser includes (or tries to) in the build. So if `fileToUse` is local, the local file is used by rvc.js during optimisation, but it also gets bundled; if it's remote, the optimisation fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's the solution I eventually settled on. It feels somewhat kludgy, but it works:

1. Stub out the loaders and the library you don't want bundled
2. Add an `onBuildWrite` function that rewrites modules depending on the library, so that they think they're requiring something else entirely - in this case `Ractive_RUNTIME`
3. Add an entry to your runtime AMD config's `paths` object, so that `Ractive_RUNTIME` points to the CDN

My optimiser config now looks like this:

```
{
  baseUrl: 'path/to/js/',
  out: 'build/js/app.js',
  name: 'app',
  optimize: 'none',

  paths: {
    'amd-loader': 'loaders/amd-loader',
    'rvc': 'loaders/rvc',
    'Ractive': 'lib/Ractive'
  },

  stubModules: [ 'amd-loader', 'rvc', 'Ractive' ],

  onBuildWrite: function ( name, path, contents ) {
    if ( contents === "define('Ractive',{});" ) {
      // this is the stub module, we can kill it
      return '';
    }

    // otherwise all references to `Ractive` need replacing
    return contents.replace( /['"]Ractive['"]/g, '"Ractive_RUNTIME"' );
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, the script that loads the app.js file created by the optimiser has a config entry that points to the CDN:

```
require.config({
  context: uniqueContext,
  baseUrl: baseUrl,

  paths: {
    'amd-loader': 'loaders/amd-loader',
    'rvc': 'loaders/rvc',
    'Ractive': 'lib/Ractive',
    'Ractive_RUNTIME': 'http://cdn.ractivejs.org/releases/0.3.9/Ractive.min'
  }
});
```